# Styling with padding in a html file

Tags: html, css, styling

I have created a simple CSS and HTML file as follows.

```css
.main {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.great-grand-parent {
  width: 900px;
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.grand-parent {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="main">Main
  <div class="great-grand-parent">Great Grand Parent
    <div class="grand-parent">Grand Parent
      <div class="parent">Parent
        <div class="child">Child
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected Result:** 
Divs with various colors with **equal** padding on four  sides.

**Actual Result:** 
Divs with various colors with **different** padding on four  sides.

**Question:**
What do I change to get the expected result?

Comment: add margin:0 auto to every class in css

Comment: @VikasJadhav That didn't help

Comment: yes.. i realize this is because of height and width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text increases the space in the boxes so if you want the text does not affect the size you must add `position: absolute`. Also, only use `width: 100%` if you want the size to fit the full width of your box or screen. If you don't need a defined height, don't add it to your code as the main box will adapt to the height of its contents. As global styles use `box-sizing: border-box`. Here is an exmaple:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.great-grand-parent {
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.grand-parent {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  background: cyan;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="main"><span>Main</span>
  <div class="great-grand-parent"><span>Great Grand Parent</span>
    <div class="grand-parent"><span>Grand Parent</span>
      <div class="parent"><span>Parent</span>
        <div class="child"><span>Child</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want height to be defined too. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Try adding a defined height to your main box and give the rest a height of 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Padding is same but because of text content it looks like that

```css
.main {

background: blue;
color: black;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 20px;  
}

.great-grand-parent {  
    background: orange;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 20px;  
}

.grand-parent {
   
    background: red;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 20px;  
}
.parent {
    
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 20px;  
}
.child {
  
    background: cyan;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 20px ;
    /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
}
```

```html
<div title="main" class="main">
    <div title="great- grand-parent" class="great-grand-parent">
        <div title="grand-parent" class="grand-parent">
            <div title="parent" class="parent"> 
                <div title="Child" class="child"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Check this image]

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Have a look at this link. The padding is the same on all boxes and they work. But... margin, border and padding are no-content areas. Then you have the content area inside where you write your text and draw the next "inner" box. So if you would remove the text, the boxes look the same. Otherwise remove the top padding and set your line-height: 20px and you will have them look all equal.

To remove the the top padding you can declare padding: 0 20px 20px.

Answer (score 0):

it is because of content inside DIV and height and width.

```css
.main {
  background: blue;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.great-grand-parent {
  background: orange;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grand-parent {
  background: red;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  background: cyan;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="great-grand-parent">
    <div class="grand-parent">
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```